# JavaScript Node.replaceChild() doesn't count new child's innerHtml

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, innerhtml

While creating a Firefox addon, I've run into a weird problem.
I have an array of nodes, returned by some iterator. Iterator returns only nodes, containing `Node.TEXT_NODE` as one or more of it's children. The script runs on page load.
I have to find some text in that nodes by regexp and surround it with a `SPAN` tag.

```
//beginning skipped  
var node = nodeList[i];    
var node_html = node.innerHTML;  
var node_content = node.textContent;  
if(node_content.length > 1){  
    var new_str = "<SPAN class='bar'>" + foo + "</SPAN>";  
    var regexp = new RegExp( foo , 'g' );  
    node_html = node_html.replace(regexp, new_str);  
    node.innerHTML = node_html;  
}
```

Basic version looked like this, and it worked except one issue - `node.innerHTML` could contain attributes, event handlers, that could also contain `foo`, that should not be surrounded with `<span>` tags.
So I decided to make replacements in text nodes only. But text nodes can't contain a HTML tag, so I had to wrap them with `<div>`. Like this:

```
var node = nodeList[i];
for(var j=0; j<node.childNodes.length; j++){
    var child = node.childNodes[j];
    var child_content = child.textContent;
    if(child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && child_content.length >1){
        var newChild = document.createElement('div');
//          var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(child_content);
//          newChild.appendChild(newTextNode);
        var new_html = child_content;            
        var new_str = "<SPAN class='bar'>" + foo + "</SPAN>";
        var regexp = new RegExp( foo , 'g' );
        new_html = new_html.replace(regexp, new_str);
        newChild.innerHTML = new_html;
        alert(newChild.innerHTML);
        node.replaceChild(newChild, child);
    }
}
```

In this case, `alert(newChild.innerHTML);` shows right html. But after the page is rendered, all `<div>`s created are empty! I'm puzzled.
If I uncomment this code:

```
//          var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(child_content);  
//          newChild.appendChild(newTextNode);
```

`alert` also shows things right, and `<div>`s are filled with text (textNode adding works ok) , but again without `<span>`s. And another funny thing is that I can't highlight that new `<div>`s' content with a mouse in browser.
Looks like it doesn't take new `innerHTML` into account, and I can't understand why.
Do I do something wrong? (I certainly do, but what? Or, is that a FF bug/feature?)

Comment: Where does "foo" come from???

Comment: could you move the `var newChild` definition outside of if? The scoping looks wrong.

Comment: @Efraim well the scoping will be OK, because of the way Javascript works.  However, it makes no sense because the variable won't be initialized if the `if` body is not executed; even if it *were* initialized, if the node isn't a text node the replacement shouldn't happen anyway!!

Comment: Well, the code looks a bit weird because it was copy-pasted from the project with some unimportant (in this case) stuff removed to make it simpler... And you're right, that "}" is in the wrong place because of that. I'll edit the code now. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in Firefox you can use fun stuff like TreeWalker and Range. You may even be able to get rid of the code that gives you the initial array of nodes.

```
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
var range = document.createRange();
var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
wrapper.className = "wrapper";
var node;
var re = /^wrap me$/;
while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
  if (re.test(node.textContent)) {
    range.selectNode(node);
    range.surroundContents(wrapper.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/azimu3/edit)

You could tweak this so only part of the text node is wrapped by setting the range differently and TreeWalker can be filtered more.

[Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) / [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/treeWalker)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Range totally suits for this task! And I need no more regexp replacement in this case!

Answer (score 0):

That code is really odd; why are those three lines *outside* of the `if` statement?

I think it should look something like this:

```
var node = nodeList[i];
for(var j=0; j<node.childNodes.length; j++){
  var child = node.childNodes[j];
  var child_content = child.textContent;
  if(child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && child_content.length >1){
    var newChild = document.createElement('div');
    newChild.innerHTML = '<span class="bar">' + child_content + '</span>';
    node.replaceChild(newChild, child);
}
```

Now I can't figure out what was going on with that regex and the replacement stuff; it makes no sense to me in the code you've posted.

Comment: Right, that three lines should be inside. My copy-paste error, fixed already.

Comment: "foo" is just a number string. Regexp is used for replacement. Doesn't matter, really, it can be different, and it worked in the first case. For simplicity, assume it's a string like `var foo='123456';